# Private key Proof of Ownership

Tags: encryption, cryptography, hash, digital-signature

Given 2 entities, A and B:

A has a public key( x ) and a private key( x* ).
B has a A's public key hash( let's call it h(x) ).

A has to prove ownership of x* to B.

How could this be achieved, considering the fact that B is not allowed to see A's keys( neither x or x* ), but only A's public key hash( h(x) )?

*Question related to [A Decentralized Digital Identity Architecture](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fbloc.2019.00017/full), section 5.4. Achieving Unlinkability With Blinded Credentials*





Diagram(Step 4 - Phase B("Online") - prove owner x*):


[image: Step 4]

Comment: Based on your comments on the answer you are not expecting a generic explanation of how ownership of a private key is proven. But you expect instead an explanation in the context of a very specific  use case and its restrictions. This use case and architecture is not explained in your question in sufficient detail but requires reading and understanding of about 20 pages text (you've provided a link to this). Based on this I consider the question too broad.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich
I believe that specifying the data that each party possesses and the constraints should be enough.
There is no "short explanation" for DID.

Comment: This is cross-posted with Cryptography. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/87258/18298

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Bob is never allowed to see Alice's public key, ever, then there's no way for Alice to prove to Bob that she owns `A*`, if Bob only has access to `h(A)` and `h` is a general-purpose hash algorithm. Bob has insufficient information.

The only way to make this work is for Alice to send Bob `A` as part of the proof. He can then compute `h(A)` and compare it against his known hash. Afterwards, Bob can send a unique challenge `C` - a sufficiently long random string will do just fine - which Alice must sign with her private key, i.e. `C* = s(C,A*)`, and return the signature to Bob. Bob can then validate the signature using `A`. Bob now has proof that Alice has `A*`. The hash `h(A)`, distributed over some trusted channel, is an anchor through which trust is established.

This type of scheme is quite common in scenarios where you want to establish secure communication between any pair (or n-tuple) of parties in a large pool of users, where distributing all of the keys for all of the users is prohibitive and inefficient due to their size and the number of users. Instead, one can distribute the *hashes* of the keys associated with users, over some trusted channel, then have the users transmit their public keys to each other over an untrusted channel.

One thing to watch out for is that the security of the entire system hinges on there being no collision attacks on `h`. If an attacker can come up with some keypair `{A', A'*}` where `h(A') = h(A)`, then they can impersonate Alice. This is possible in practice for MD5 and SHA-1, and theoretically possible for other hash functions that use Merkle-Damgård construction, such as SHA-2. It would be better to use SHA-3, which uses a different construction and is expected to have better resistance to this class of attack.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea behind such proof is that A signs some  message ("challenge") created by B with its private key - and that this signature can be checked.

B creates a random challenge which is then signed by A. It is important that this challenge is not predictable in order to avoid replay attacks. A then sends the signed challenge and the public key to B. B can compare the provided public key against the already known fingerprint (public key hash) and can check the signature with the verified public key. If the signature is as expected then A is the owner of the private key, assuming that the private key was not compromised.

> ... considering the fact that B is not allowed to see A's keys

The public key is considered **public**, hence the name. It is not a secret and A can send it to B.

Comment: The overall architecture does not allow B to see A's public key directly.

Comment: It's a requirement for the decentralized identities architecture.

Comment: @SergiuNistor:  The title asks about a more general concept for proof of ownership. As for the very specific architecture you point out as *related* only: it looks like the public keys and signature are stored on a distributed ledger - which makes these accessible by B. So the general concept of providing public key and signature to B is still the same.

Comment: x is not being stored on the ledger. CP([x]) is being stored. CP([x]) is actually the signed blinded public key, which does not help. After unsigning and unblinding the key, we will get x's hash( h(x) ).

Comment: OP, can you please elaborate on the use case for such a system?

Comment: https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fbloc.2019.00017/full

It is being explained in the article I provided in the original post.